# Maven commands in shell scripts

Tags: java, shell, maven

I'm trying to create a script which can build a number of different Maven projects where each has it's own pom.xml file.

So from the parent directory I wish to run the command 
`mvn -f Project1/pom.xml clean`
This works fine from the command line but if I place it into a shell script and execute it, it fails with unknown lifecycle phase "clean".

The overall goal is to have a sequence of these commands executing within a script i.e.

1. `mvn -f Project1/pom.xml clean`
2. `mvn -f Project2/pom.xml clean`
3. `mvn -f Project3/pom.xml clean`

with the calling script residing in the parent directory.

Comment: a parent pom would be a better approach

Comment: print the error that you are getting. That will be helpful to answer your question

Comment: @Philipp could you elaborate on the parent pom solution or provide some links with more info, I'm new to Maven. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Also: can you please show how your script looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a script is not the best solution for this. I would create parent pom and add your projects as modules. This way it will work on all OS and you can applay any goals you want.

Here are some helpful tutorials:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-web-spring-sect-simple-parent.html